Trying to buy sol but the buy page doesn't load
When I go to buy thru coinbase on ramp more times than not the send page loads instead and I can't buy!!

I’m voting to close this question because it is spam

At the current time, Solana is very popular and sites such as Coinbase may be struggling to handle the demand.

Possible solutions could be to try at quieter times of the day
Change Internet providers (your wifi / hotspot)
Try a different exchange?

